# asp.net core webapi - debugging unexpectedly shuts off in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

**AuthController - Authenticate action**

```
[HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Login>> Authenticate([FromBody] Login login)
        {
            // login will come in from the device with basic auth
            var c = 0;
            string token = string.Empty;
            
            try
            {

                bool isAuth = _unitOfWork.Logins.GetAuthenticateUser(username, password);
                if(isAuth == false)
                {
                    var msg = "Authentication Failed";
                    login.Message = msg;
                    return new JsonResult(login);
                }

                Jwt j = new Jwt(_unitOfWork);
                try
                {
                    login.Token = j.CreateToken(username);
                    SessionModel session = new SessionModel();
                    session.SessionStart = DateTime.Now;
                    login.SessionStart = session.SessionStart;
                    session.UserName = username;
                    session.Token = login.Token;
                    await _unitOfWork.Sessions.AddAsync(session);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //delete session if there is jwt error
                    
                    var msg = $"Error message from create token - Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException} Exception Message: {ex.Message} Source: {ex.Source}";
                    
                    return UnAuthorized;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = $"Error message from Header Auth decode - Inner Exception: {ex.InnerException} Exception Message: {ex.Message} Source: {ex.Source}";
                login.Message = msg;
                return new JsonResult(login);
            }
            //return login obj with token, msg, session datetime
            return new JsonResult(login);
        }
```

The above code all runs as expected until it reached the line at the end
`return new JsonResult(login);`
At that point Visual Studio exits debugging in IIS Express without warning or error.
I am testing the api with Postman.

When I execute in Postman, I get a status 200 but I do not get the expected Json result. That is at the point where Visual Studio drops out and terminates the debugging session.

Comment: I am using Task<ActionResult<ClassType>> in many of my WebAPI methods.  In this case you should just be able to return 'login'.  No need to put it in a JsonResult.  I presume your controller inherits "ControllerBase" and is decorated with [ApiController] attribute.

Comment: Could you please share your visual studio version? I suggest you could try to use visual studio installer to update your visual studio to the newest version and try again.

Comment: @BrandoZhang Community Edition version 16.7.7